# Mapping plotly 3d colorscale to radial coordinate instead of z

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, plotly

By default, plotly 3d surface plots map the colorscale to the `z` coordinate. Now I am trying to plot 3d radiation patterns with plotly, as you can see [here](https://plot.ly/4/~gevero/). In this case it would be ideal to map the colorscale to the radial coordinate instead of `z`, since in this case `z` has no actual physical meaning while the radial coordinate represent the radiation intensity in a given direction. Hence the question: is it possible to remap the plotly colorscale to a new numpy array, which in this case would represent the radial coordinate? The code used to generate the plot is reported below, where `m_x, m_y, m_z` are the numpy array containing the data.

```
data = go.Data([go.Surface(
                       x=m_x,
                       y=m_y,
                       z=m_z)])
layout = go.Layout(
title='radiation_pattern',
autosize=True,
width=800,
height=800,
margin=go.Margin(
    l=65,
    r=50,
    b=65,
    t=90
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question but could you not just swap the axis?

Comment: @Cleb I cannot really swap the axis, because my surface must be defined by 3 2d numpy arrays (x,y,z) and instead my radial coordinate is defined as r=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)

Comment: but could you then not just define your arrays as (z, y, x)? It would not affect the sqrt but in the plot, x is then treated as z and is therefore used as the colorscale or am I missing something?

Comment: Defining my array as (z,y,x) would simply rotate my radiation pattern, with the colorscale being mapped to x. Instead I need my radiation pattern to be exactly defined as (x,y,z), and on top of that the colorscale mapped to a fourth array (different from x,y,z) defined as r=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2), i.e. the coloring is a function of the distance from the origin.

Comment: Ok, then I might have misunderstood. It would probably help if you added some data and code; that makes it easier to tackle the problem.

Comment: I will add the code to question!